# How to convert a character chain into a ASCII

Tags: arrays, c, function, ascii

I would like to know how I could transform a character string to an ASCII value, such as "12ASD132 hello" in its ASCII values

a greeting,

Comment: I made an attempt to answer your first question, but your second question seems incredibly vague: "if you have entered a character to skip an error".  I don't know what kind of answer you are looking for there.  I suggest that you just edit your question and remove that part, since it seems unrelated and vague.  This site works best if you just ask one question at a time.  You can use the "Ask Question" button to ask a new question.

Comment: I will keep that in mind for future questions, I am new to this community and I am getting familiar with the website, thank you very much

Comment: @kevinsimon: Note that you can [edit] your question to improve it. As long as you don't have any existing answers that would be invalidated, there is nothing wrong with removing the second part of the question. At the time of this writing, all existing answers only address the first part of your question.

Comment: modified the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question: all C implementations I have ever seen store their characters in ASCII, so if your implementation is like that too, you can simply print each character in the string as an integer:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  const char * str = "12ASD132 hello";
  for (const char * p = str; *p; p++) {
    printf("%d\n", *p);
  }
}
```

Comment: "all... I have ever seen store their characters in ASCII," --> The LHSOE: lonely heart society of [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) cordially invites you to their next meeting. 

Answer (score 0):

```
char *str = "12ASD132 hello";

printf("ch\tASCII\tASCII(HEX)\n");
while(*str)
{
    printf("'%c'\t%d\t0x%02x\n", *str, *str, *str);
    str++;
}
```